Problemas con mi editor VSCode (Creo que es el scriptcs pero no encuentro solucion)
hace un tiempo he venido programando en VisualCode pero cuando intento correr el codigo en mi editor me da un error en la pestaña Output, el error es el siguiente:
[Running] scriptcs "c:\Users\juand\Desktop\C#\Program.cs"
"scriptcs" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.
[Done] exited with code=1 in 2.002 seconds
tengo la carpeta de scriptcs en la misma carpeta donde estoy haciendo mi proyecto y ya he intentado solucionarlo agregandola al path y una infinidad de cosas diferentes pero nada me ayuda co eso, si alguien podria ayudarme se lo agradeceria mucho.

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! que es scriptcs ???

"Y una infinidad de cosas" Entonces, ahora podría ser cualquier cosa. Empieza por comunicar claramente el error, ya sea con una captura de pantalla (en este caso aplicaría) o copiando completamente el error como texto, después puedes listar lo que has intentado. Agrega cuantos detalles puedas.

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
